# SharePoint 2010 Markup Styles menu bug in Internet Explorer

Tags: 2010

Hoping someone can help with this. We have come across a bug in the Markup Styles menu in page edit mode in SharePoint 2010, however it seems only to be an issue in certain Internet Explorer versions.

Basically, what we've seen is that when you highlight text, and then activate the Markup Styles menu and try to move the mouse pointer down the menu, the screen jumps back down the page to the text I tried to edit, preventing me from using the menu!

When I try it in Firefox, it's absolutely fine. It's also OK on my version of IE8, but when I try it on IE9, I get this problem.

Has anyone come across this before, and found a solution?

Comment: Is there any other branding applied or is the design pure SharePoint?

Comment: Hi did you get a solution for this bug/problem? thanks